# Why have I lost my Settings application?

Tags: 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS updated as soon as I am notified it is available. This is for my laptop and tower. Last week the Settings icon was on my Dock. Early this week, it disappeared. When I try to access Settings by clicking on the upper right corner I get an hour glass cursor for a while and that is it. (The drop down list includes Settings and Power Off/Log off.) The only devices with which it seems to connect are the ones that are already pair with it. So far, that is my Galaxy Tab 3 Lite SM-T110.
Strangely enough, this happened to my laptop before the tower. Could it be something in the updates issued early this week?

Answer (score 1):

I did and additional search and solved the problem. In a terminal I typed:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

This solves the problem for both the laptop and tower.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, remember to click the big check mark